# How to apply range on multiple slices in golang Beego template?

Tags: go, beego, go-templates

I have a struct, containing two slices with same size, which is to be passed to the template.

```
type V struct {
    Process         []string
    ProcessType     []string
}
```

I need to iterate the slices in same range. In golang(without a framework) we could do this as follows

```
//I know all of you know this. Added for better understanding of my problem.
{{range $i, $e := .Process}} 
    {{.}} 
    {{index $.ProcessType $i}}
{{end}}
```

We could apply range on a slice in beego like this

```
{{range $key, $val := .vm.Process}} //this.Data["vm"] = V (Struct V is passed as vm to the template)
    {{$val}}
{{end}}
```

How to include slice ProcessType in this range too?

Comment: @JiangYD Thanks.. I already have a struct with Process and ProcessType. My question was how to use it together in  Beego template range.

Comment: how about use a custom function `get(idx int, slc interface{})` http://beego.me/docs/mvc/view/template.md